# How to iterate over the Observable collection in c#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following class model shown below.

```
 public abstract partial class KeyItemBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public KeyItemBase() : this(null, Enumerable.Empty<KeyItemBase>()) { }

        public KeyItemBase(string key, IEnumerable<KeyItemBase> children)
        {
            this.m_key = key;
            this.m_children = new ObservableCollection<KeyItemBase>(children);
        }

        string m_key;
        public string key 
        { 
            get { return m_key; }
            set
            {
                m_key = value;
                RaisedOnPropertyChanged("key");
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<KeyItemBase> m_children;
        public ObservableCollection<KeyItemBase> Children { get { return m_children; } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisedOnPropertyChanged(string _PropertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_PropertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract partial class KeyItemBase
    {
        // Generate clean JSON on re-serialization.
        public bool ShouldSerializeChildren() { return Children != null && Children.Count > 0; }
    }

    public sealed class KeyItem : KeyItemBase
    {
        // Use for a JSON object with no T_id property.
        // Bind an appropriate SfTreeView.ItemTemplate to this type.

        public KeyItem() : base() { }

        public KeyItem(string key, IEnumerable<KeyItemBase> children) : base(key, children) { }
    }

    public class KeyIdItem : KeyItemBase
    {
        // Use for a JSON object with a T_id property.
        // Bind an appropriate SfTreeView.ItemTemplate to this type.

        public KeyIdItem() : base() { }

        public KeyIdItem(string key, IEnumerable<KeyItemBase> children, long t_id) : base(key, children) { this.m_id = t_id; }

        long m_id;
        public long T_id 
        { 
            get { return m_id; }
            set
            {
                m_id = value;
                RaisedOnPropertyChanged("T_id");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class KeyItemFactory
    {
        public static KeyItemBase ToKeyObject(string name, long? id, IEnumerable<KeyItemBase> children)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new KeyItem(name, children);
            else
                return new KeyIdItem(name, children, id.Value);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<KeyItemBase> ToKeyObjects(JToken root)
        {
            return root.TopDescendantsWhere<JObject>(o => true)
                .Select(o => ToKeyObject(((JProperty)o.Parent).Name, (long?)o["T_id"], ToKeyObjects(o)));
        }
    }
```

The following line of code,
`var items = new ObservableCollection<KeyItemBase>(KeyItemFactory.ToKeyObjects(root));`

returns me an observable collection of ObservableCollection type.

Problem #1: I want to be able to iterate using a foreach or any other approach to access all of the "m_children" for each of the "m_key".

```
Output ObservableCollection<KeyObjectBase>: 
[
  {
    "T_id": 0,
    "key": "Soccer",
    "Children": [
      {
        "key": "Clubs",
        "Children": [
          {
            "T_id": 1,
            "key": "ClubA"
          },
          {
            "T_id": 2,
            "key": "ClubB"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "Subs",
        "Children": [
          {
            "T_id": 3,
            "key": "SubA",
            "Children": [
              {
                "T_id": 3,
                "key": "SubE"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "Subs_Used",
        "Children": [
          {
            "T_id": 3,
            "key": "SubK"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Problem #2: My ultimate goal is to create a treeview-like structure in xamarin forms from the "key" and "Children" information that I have and I am going step by step.

I thought I could have one root treeview node and iterate over its children till and add those children to the root node but I am not able to put this concept from my head into a workable method. I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Currently, I have the list like this without the text visible.

[image: TreeView without the text field]

Comment: to iterate through a tree structure you either write your own depth-or-breadth based algorithm.  Both are fairly trivial to do

Comment: @Jason I did something like the following but it doesnt seem to do the task. ``` foreach (var subitem in items)
                {
                    foreach (var child in subitem.Children)
                    {
                        while (child.Children.Count > 0)
                        {
                            subnode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeViewNode() { Content = child.key });
                            MenuItemsRoot.Add(new KeyIdItem(child.key, child.Children, 10));
                        }
                    }
                }```

Comment: generally depth/breadth based algorithms are recursive

Comment: @Jason I am confused on how to implement the recursive algo. May you please give me some guidance? It would be very appreicaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should visit every node in the tree

```
private void RecurseTree(SomeClass node)
{
  // visit each child node of the current node
  foreach(var n in node.Children)
  {
    RecurseTree(n);
  }

  // do any processing on the current node here

}
```

you call it by passing in the root node

```
RecurseTree(root);
```

Comment: I understand that this will help me to build the treenode but I am not understand how can I access the contents of the observable collection from the code line ```var items = new ObservableCollection<KeyItemBase>(KeyItemFactory.ToKeyObjects(root));```

Comment: `foreach (var x in items) { ... }`

Comment: I did that but I can only access the "Soccer" and not its nested children. That is why i am so confused. I mentioned it in the comment above as well but its doesnt work. :/

Comment: are you sure that your nested json data is actually getting converted to a nested object model?

Comment: It is converted to a nested model as described in the code above. I am not understanding on how to access the property of the class.

Comment: `x` should be type `KeyItemBase` which has a `Children` property, so have you tried `x.Children`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194397/discussion-between-laura-smith-and-jason).

Comment: I did the following, ``` foreach (KeyItemBase item in items)
                {
                    foreach (KeyItemBase keyItemBase in item.Children)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"{item.key} has a child {keyItemBase.key}!");
                    }
                }``` but I get "Soccer" has a child "Clubs", but I dont even access the 'ClubA" and "ClubB"

Comment: I am able to now have a nested structure like this image but without the text visible. Not sure what is wrong.